# Why it is not possible to reach the sun if we are able to create plasma?

Tags: temperature, nuclear-physics, plasma-physics, fusion, nuclear-engineering

if we are able to create plasma in isolated environment possessing temperature much more than temperature of sun then why are we not able to create something that can go to the sun?

Comment: If I can extinguish a candle flame by pinching the wick with my fingers, why can't I do the same to put out a five-alarm house fire?

Comment: The Parker Solar Probe will get pretty close - at its closest approach to the Sun it will be about 8.5 solar radii above the Sun's surface.

Comment: Question seems obvious and clear to me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Temperature is only one aspect of the equation.  In the case of the experiments, the high temperature plasma was a small quantity of matter, carefully isolated from everything around it.  The chamber itself is designed to be able to sink the small amount of energy emitted from the plasma.

Now I say small with some degree of certainty.  You don't specify which experiments you are referring to, but I can point to [this particular one](https://www.imperial.ac.uk/news/242258/breakthrough-fusion-experiment-generates-excess-energy/) from last year as an example.  In it, the fusion reaction emitted rougly 3,000,000 Joules of energy.  Now three million may seem like a lot, but a Joule is a small quantity.  3,000,000 Joules is actually about the energy of 3 chocolate bars.  When working with the sun, there's a lot more energy at stake.  The sun [outputs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orders_of_magnitude_(energy)) 380,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000 Joules every second!

Now the key to the comparison here is that in the reactor, we have the ability to sink that small amount of energy into the surroundings.  Inside the sun, at its core, the surroundings themselves are at 27 million degrees. And, no matter how much you try to sink that heat to cool it off, the sun has more heat energy to give.  If you are surrounded by 27 million degrees, it does not take long for radiative heating to bring all of your surfaces up to temperatures where they cease to be structural.

Yes, I'm being a bit melodramatic quoting the $3.8\cdot 10^{26} \text J$ of energy emitted by the sun.  You don't see all of that - it's being emitted in all directions; not all of it is focused on your solar probe.  But the point is, it has so much energy to spare that you won't be able to sink the energy the way you can sink a mere $3\cdot10^6 \text J$ joules.  Not only are they different orders of manitude, quite literally the order of magnitude difference is, itself, more than an order of magnitude apart.

Comment: Are we talking Hershey bars, or Nestle bars? And I thought the Krispy Kream donut was the standard unit...

Answer (score 5):

A nuclear fusion reactor uses several hundred Megawatt of power to get it working ( https://euro-fusion.org/faq/power-to-start-the-reactor/ ). This is effectively the output of a whole power station. You just don't have the required electrical power available on a space probe to create the magnetic fields required to protect the probe from the high energy particles emitted by the sun.

Answer (score 5):

> then why are we not able to create something that can go to the sun

The outer surface is hot, but not *that* hot, around 5600 C. It would not be that difficult to engineer a solution that will last for some time at least. If one wanted it to last a longer time, it would have to be cooled, and that presents a problem, because you need to be hotter than the surroundings to reject the heat and that's difficult at these sorts of temperatures.

Unfortunately there's basically no way to send back data. The sun is so bright that there's no way you're getting a signal back that you can read from a safe distance, it's just way to noisy. Maybe a skimmer that spends only a few moments in and then races back out on a tangent would work, recording as it goes. [Or maybe you use a big laser as a cooling dump and a comms system too](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sundiver).